# GroupCount by Multiple Values

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have data structured as so:

```
{
    number: Integer
    letter: String
}
```

I'd like to do a group count by both properties like so:

```
g.V().values('number', 'letter').groupCount();
```

and see the data displayed as so:

```
[[1,A]:16, [1,B]:64, [2,A]:78, [2,B]:987]
```

Is there any way to do this in tinkerpop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple

```
g.V().groupCount().by(values('number', 'letter').fold())
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do a groupCount on properties from related Vertices as well a project() will do the job (values() does not handle traversal only simple properties on the object).

Let's say your letter is a property of an adjacent Vertex (using an outgoing edge in this case (but might as well be ingoing, use in()) and number is a property of your current/starting Vertex:

```
g.V().project('number', 'letter').
  by(values('number')).
  by(out('<outgoing-edge-label>').values('letter')).
  groupCount()
```

In many cases it's powerful, it can be arbitrary traversals and/or properties in the by statements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer avoid lambdas if at all possible; but this is how it can be done with a lambda (if it turns out to be impossible to do it without a lambda).

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
g.V().sideEffect(it -> {
    String letter = (String) it.get().property("letter").value());
    Integer number = (Integer) it.get().property("number").value());
    if (map.get(letter) == null)
        map.put(letter, new HashMap<>());
    if (map.get(letter).get(number) == null)
        map.get(letter).put(number, 1);
    else 
        map.get(letter).put(number, map.get(letter).get(number) + 1);
}).iterate();
```

It's approximately the same speed as

```
g.V().values('number', 'letter').groupCount();
```