Represent count as a two-dimensional table
The requirement is pretty simple - I have set of vertices, that have two properties (let's say 'name' and 'job title'). I would like to count how many combinations of each I have and represent it as a two-dimensional table, for example:




Programmer
Driver




John
3
56


Peter
0
8



Can I do it in Gremlin?
I tried to use groupCount(), but I do not know how to make it work with two properties

Did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712466/groupcount-by-multiple-values

Maybe not in a tabular format, but Gremlin can return a map of what you're looking for using the project() step.
I don't know how you're graph is structured, so I can't really give an example query based on your data.  However, if I have a graph of movie data where I have nodes of Artists connected to movies over different edges that determine the Artist's involvement:
(Artist) <- [:actor,actress,director] - (movie)

I can get an output of the number of times an Artist was involved via different roles via:
g.V().hasLabel('Artist').limit(50).
    project('name','actor','director').
        by(values('name')).
        by(in('actor','actress').count()).
        by(in('director').count())

That returns a map of the following:
{'actor': 0, 'director': 2, 'name': 'Joe Catalanotto'}
{'actor': 0, 'director': 2, 'name': 'Mark A. Catalena'}
{'actor': 1, 'director': 4, 'name': 'Feliciano Catalán'}
{'actor': 0, 'director': 2, 'name': 'Manuel Catalán'}
{'actor': 0, 'director': 1, 'name': 'Cirina Catania'}
{'actor': 2, 'director': 1, 'name': 'Alfredo Catania'}


Thank you very much for the response, this does make sense. One problem i have is the "in" bit - I am not familiar with it and my version of Gremlin does not seem to recognise it and throws 'unexpected token' error. What is it suppose to do? Thank you

The in() and out() steps traverse edges in the direction of the edge in respect of the vertex that you're coming from.  So in this case, I have incoming edges into my Artist vertices.  So I'm traversing across the inward facing edge.  Depending on the programming language you're using, sometimes in is a reserved word and you may need to express it as in_().

Ah yes, it is obvious now. I will try in_
